# WPF: Run Validator on two comboboxes as the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, combobox

I have the following two comboboxes that contain similar list of items.  The two comboboxes cannot have the same value.

```
            <ComboBox Name="OldEmpNoListBox"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding OldEmpNoCollection}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Model.FieldNameForOldEmpNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Width="150"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Model" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <vm:FieldNamesValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.Text>
            </ComboBox>

            <ComboBox Name="OldCompanyListBox"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding OldCompanyCollection}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Model.FieldNameForOldCompany, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Width="150"
                      Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Model" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <vm:FieldNamesValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.Text>
            </ComboBox>
```

Here is the Validator:

```
/// <summary>
/// Duplicate Values Validator
/// </summary>
public class FieldNamesValidator : ValidationRule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validate OldEmpNo field name does not match Old Company field name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="cultureInfo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        EmpNoOptionsSettingsModel _empNoOptions = (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).ParametersEmpNoOptionsViewModel.Model;

        // if OldEmpNo field name = Old Company field name
        if (_empNoOptions.FieldNameForOldEmpNo == _empNoOptions.FieldNameForOldCompany)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Field name for Old Emp No cannot be the same as the field name for Old Company");
        }           

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

The validation works as expected except that it only operates on whichever combobox is currently being changed.  For instance, if the comboboxes have the same value, each box is outlined in red.  I change the first box and the red is removed, but the red remains on the second box.  Is there a way to get both comboboxes to validate themselves anytime one of them is changed?

Comment: What is `Model` property to which Text is binded to? Isn't it supposed to be `FieldNameForOldEmpNo` and `FieldNameForOldCompany`?

Comment: I am using SimpleMVVM so `Model` is a copy of the DataContext.  I tried `Model.FieldNameForOldEmpNo` and `Model.FieldNameForOldCompany`, but that didn't seem to make a difference.  I was hoping that by listening to any changes on the `Model` the validator would fire, regardless of which field was changed.

Comment: No, validation rule gets fired only when binding source is changed. I have posted an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Validation rule gets fired on binding source property
>   changed event.

Change property name in binding to point to actual property:

```
<ComboBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Model.FieldNameForOldEmpNo" 
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        .....
</ComboBox.Text>
```

and

```
<ComboBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Model.FieldNameForOldCompany" 
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        .....
</ComboBox.Text>
```

And from setter of both of these properties, raise property change for other property as well so that its corresponding validation rule gets fired.